# How to set up on default View Quick Edit

Tags: quick-edit

In SharePoint there is a Quick Edit Button in the Library ribbon under "View Format".

How can I enable the library to be shown in Quick Edit mode as the default?

Could I make a "Quick Edit" view?

Comment: Do you want to show a QuickEdit View by default? OR you want to open the Ribbon by default? Or is there any issue with QuickEdit button in your site?

Comment: I want to have a View with set Quick Edit button by default.

Comment: Added answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are wanting the document library to show the Quick Edit View by default just follow these steps.

1. Create a new view. Beneath "+ new document" you should see "All Documents" click on the dots to the right and click "Create View".
2. On the View Type page that appears click the view type of "Datasheet View" (in the right column usually)

[image: Choosing the View Type]

3. Name the view what you wish in the Name section and be sure to check the "Make this the default view" box, be sure to check the columns you want to display as needed. Then click "Ok" at the top or the bottom of the page.

[image: Setting this created view as the default/settings too]

4. You will be back at the library page and the default view will now show your documents listed in the Quick Edit mode!

[image: Quick Edit is now the shown on opening the default view.]

Comment: @Grzegorz Z did this work for you?

Comment: Bo I tried, but I have got Excel View, not Quick Edit View. Sometimes I have got Excel View in some Libraries, and sometimes I have got Quick Edit on the View. I don't know why.

Comment: I just added some images to the steps. Perhaps they will help.

Comment: Yes i tried this, but after this i have got Excel View with access. Not Quick Edit.

Comment: Can you edit your question above to include a screenshot of what you DO get after following my steps? I just want to see what you're seeing so I can possibly help you get what you want at the end.

Answer (score 7):

Add a custom button above your List View Web Part.

execute the following JS functions on click of it.

Use this to open Quick Edit:

```
InitGridFromView(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
```

Use this to exit Grid View:

```
ExitGrid(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
```

You can also use the following code to check the status of web part:

```
var gridinfo = GetCtxFromView(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
        if (gridinfo.inGridMode) {
        //in grid mode
        }else{
        //in normal mode
        }
```

If you want to open the Quick Edit view by default, create a data sheet view instead of standard view.

Comment: But how implement it to the view ? By Script webpart ?

Comment: add a content editor webpart, point it to a html file in your SiteAssets or somewhere. write html markup for the button and add this script.

Comment: While the accepted answer is the right one for this specific question, this is an *awesome* StackExchange answer, showing exactly what many of us here really *want* to know and not just the basics! Thank you!

Comment: To get the exact wpq Number, we have to place the script in postrender method of jslink for webpart. We can get the wpq Number using ctx.wpq

Answer (score 5):

Create a New View the way @calebben3 describes. Select Datasheet View

[image: Datasheet view]

and make it default view
[image: Make it default view]

Next time You open the library it will show up in Quick Edit mode ( same as Datasheet view).

Comment: Not sure why you posted almost the exact answer as @calebben3? It would be preferable to instead suggest an edit to that answer (since the only difference at the time was the screenshots).

Comment: Sorry for that @RobertLindgren . Just wanted to "visualize" the answer a little bit more. It should have been an edit....

Comment: No problem, we are all new in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about this button?

[image]

To have access to that button, you need to have at least Edit permission on the site.

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom Quick Edit button to your page or view, add a Script Editor web part and embed the following code. Make sure you change the number in [WPQ2SchemaData] to the web part number of the list/library you want to Quick Edit. You can find that by inspecting the list/library web part using Developer Tools (F12).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="QuickEditFunction();return false;">Quick Edit</button>

<script>
function QuickEditFunction()
{
InitGridFromView(window['WPQ2SchemaData'].View);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```