# SharePoint 2010 Trigger JavaScript when going to Edit Mode

Tags: 2010, javascript, content-editor-web-part, edit

So I'm looking for some JavaScript code that will trigger once a user goes into Edit mode on a page. I basically want to have two layouts in a content editor. One for display and one for edit. I have found plenty of examples of detecting if a page is in Edit mode, the problem is I can't find an event to listen to, to see if the user has gone into Edit mode. Only thing I can think of is a While loop but that seems messy. Also I want this script to be a attach and forget so I would like to avoid having to edit the page itself in designer.

Comment: You can have a custom button in content editor webpart and trigger edit mode from there, I've implemented something like this in 2013 not sure if this works in 2010. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/how-to-set-up-on-default-view-quick-edit/151523#151523

Comment: I believe you can define a function on page load, something like a function on document.ready which can help you with what needs to be shown and what needs to be hidden.

Comment: Tried to do a windows.onload but it breaks my page. I can't click on the 'page' tab and when I try to edit through site actions, it says, "Unable to get property 'PageState' of undefined or null reference". Then when I remove the code it works fine. My code below...                               
<script src="../SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery-1.12.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function() {
                console.log("hit");
           }
</script>

Comment: and a jQuery document.ready doesn't recognize a load when switching to edit mode

Comment: Also attempted to use 

 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("testing");

and while it fires my function, it doesn't fire on switching to edit mode

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways.

First:

```
$("#EditButtonID").click(function() {
    if(SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.isInEditMode()) FunctionToTrigger();
});
```

Second:

```
$("#EditButtonID").click(function() {
    if($(this).text() == "Stop") FunctionToTrigger();
});
```

If it doesn't work, you can add a `setTimeOut()` to wait 1 second or less just before *if*s

Comment: Yeah I thought of this too but the issue with that is that there is a few different edit button ids on a site. You can go through the ribbon or you can edit through site actions. Also I think the id changes based on if its a wiki page or not. In the end I decided to look for a PageState after a refresh. The page doesn't refresh after entering edit mode but it does when you edit the the content editor and really I just need the script to apply to the content editor.